# "Не судима" пишется слитно или раздельно?

Tags: орфография, частица-не, слитно-раздельно

> не судима

Как пишется, слитно или раздельно?

Comment: @79046708193, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Раздельно, поскольку по смыслу это прямое отрицание действия над человеком в прошлом (не была судима, ранее её не судили). Это краткая форма стр. причастия с отрицанием. Она не может выступать в качестве прилагательного (не выражает внутренних качеств человека, в отличие от напр. "неподсудный, неподсуден" - он таков, что его нельзя судить; "неподкупный, неподкупен" - он честный, и его нельзя подкупить).

В строгом смысле слова, "не судима" - условный перенос формы настоящего времени в прошлое, упрощение от подразумеваемого (не была судима, не судилась, не судившаяся ранее), но такая форма закрепилась за смыслом, связанным с прошлым. Совместно с этим в характерных ситуациях применяется и форма прошедшего времени - глагола "привлекаться": (ранее) не судима, (к иной ответственности) не привлекалась.

Answer (score 1):

Причастия в краткой форме пишутся с НЕ раздельно.